# Typehinting an unpack assignment

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Does anyone know how to properly typehint an unpack assignment - if it's even possible?

To clearify what I mean:

```py
data = some_function_without_typehint()

x: str = data[0]
y: int = data[1]
# x any y have typehint support

x,y = data # no typehint support

# is anything like this possible in v3.8+ ?
x: str, y: int = data
x,y : str, int = data
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: isn't that automatically inferred from the type hint of the tuple?

Comment: my IDE (IntelliJ) shows proper type hints for x and y so I assume it does infer it automatically, which is logical because you exactly know what types are in the tuple

Comment: Yes, my bad :D The tuple isn't typed in my case,so let me update the question real quick :D

Answer (score 4):

Variable annotations aren't allowed with unpacking. You have to annotate the names separately from the actual assignment.

```
x: str
y: str
x, y = data
```

The rules can be seen in the definition of an [annotated assignment](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#annotated-assignment-statements)

```
annotated_assignment_stmt ::=  augtarget ":" expression
                               ["=" (starred_expression | yield_expression)]
```

and the definition of an `augtarget`:

```
augtarget                 ::=  identifier | attributeref | subscription | slicing
```

The lack of multiple targets is explicitly called out:

> The difference from normal Assignment statements is that only single target is allowed.

---

(It's not entirely clear to me *why* you can't annotate the targets individually. I usually just assume it has something to do with ambiguity and LL(1) grammars. Too much lookahead needed, perhaps, to tell if `x: str, y` is `x` annotated with `str, y` or `x` annotated with `str` and `y` being another target.)

(After typing that, it seems likely. While the new PEG grammar is *not* so restricted, there may not be a compelling reason to change existing grammar rules to take advantage of it.)

Comment: thanks for the details! Sad that it isn't supported though...

Answer (score 2):

You can type-hint the variable you get from the function:

```
data:Tuple[str, int] = some_function_without_typehint()
```

and then when you unpack, the types should be inferred correctly

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, that's what I'm going to do ;)

Answer (score 0):

As @MarcinCuprjak and @chepner suggested, I ended up annotating the `data` variable as a whole, so types are inferred during unpacking.

Hoped annotations were possible during unpacking, but thanks to @chepner's explanation, this isn't the case :)